# Jpa @OnetoOne relationship

Tags: java, jpa

> This is my entity class Author

```
@Entity
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "LAST1")
private String last;

@Column(name="FIRST1")
private String first;

@Lob
@Column(name = "BIO")
private String bio;

@OneToOne

private AuthorDetail authorId;
```

> getters and setters & zero parameter constructor
>
> this is my other entity AuthorDetail here i have mapped using  @OneToOne(optional = false,mappedBy = "authorDetail")

```
 @Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "ADDRESS1")
private String address1;

@Column(name="ADDRESS2")
private String address2;

@Column(name = "CITY")
private String city;

@Column(name = "STATE1")
private String state;

@Column(name = "ZIP")
private String zip;

@Column(name = "START_DATE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date startDate;

@Lob
@Column(name = "NOTES")
private String notes;

@OneToOne(optional = false,mappedBy = "authorDetail")
private Author authorId;
```

> getters and setters
>   this my main class

```
`EntityTransaction entr=em.getTransaction();
        entr.begin();
        Author author=new Author();
        author.setFirst("MD");
        author.setLast("RAHMATH");
        author.setBio("A Software Developer");

        Set detailSet=new HashSet<AuthorDetail>();
        AuthorDetail detail=new AuthorDetail();
        detail.setAddress1("Address1");
        detail.setAddress2("Address2");
        detail.setCity("NoMansLand");
        detail.setState("ZZ");
        detail.setZip("12345");
        detail.setNotes("This is test detail");
        detailSet.add(detail);
        em.persist(author);
        entr.commit();`
```

> i am getting exceptions if i try run the program

Comment: What are you using the detailSet set for?  Shouldn't you be setting author's authId using the new detail?  Please also post the exceptions you get as they help point out the problems

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single-directional relation, you don't need to write @OneToOne in both class.
From the given piece of code, it appears that you want the bi-direction relationship between Author detail and Author.

For the other side to be aware of the relation (bidirectional), it is required to add the mappedBy attribute to the @OneToOne annotation. This attribute references the (Java) property in the entity that is the owner of the relationship. In your case, in AuthorDetail class you need to add;

`@OneToOne(optional = false,mappedBy = "authorId")
private Author authorId;`

In mappedBy property, you need to give reference to the entity not class name.

Comment: Author author = new Author();
 author.setFirst("MD");
 author.setLast("RAHMATH");
 author.setBio("A Software Developer");
 //Set<AuthorDetail> detailSet;
 //detailSet = new HashSet<AuthorDetail>();
  AuthorDetail detail = new AuthorDetail();
  detail.setAddress1("Address1");
  detail.setAddress2("Address2");
 detail.setCity("NoMansLand");
  detail.setState("ZZ");           detail.setZip("12345");
            detail.setNotes("This is test detail");
            detail.setAuthorId(author); how to set the value for authorId

Answer (score 0):

In your `Author` change the following:

```
@OneToOne
private AuthorDetail authorId;
```

To:

```
@OneToOne
private AuthorDetail authorDetail;
```